# Android Get Image Source By Tag

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am trying to get an image source when I click on the image. I have an `android:tag` set with the URI. Example:

```
android:tag="@drawable/black_rook"
```

In my code I do this:

```
int imageId = (Integer) myImage.getTag();
newImage.setImageResource(imageId);
```

However, I get an error saying this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

This happens on the line where I cast to an `Integer`. How am I supposed to get the image source or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast an xml String to an Integer, as the `getTag` method does not actually return the drawable id that you want to do, but I see that you want to display a black rook. This makes me think you are making a chess application. A chess piece should be an object in itself, called "Rook". In this "Rook" object you can have an ImageView, and then make getters and setters for this objects ImageView. Then, to get the ImageView, you may simply do this:

```
Rook blackRook = new Rook();
blackRook.getImageView();
```

Just an idea, seeing as it is not such a good idea (nor a practical one) to represent a whole piece as an ImageView.

Update:

After some thought, if you really wish to proceed the way you are doing (which you shouldn't) here is what I would call a "ghetto" solution:

You first find the imageView object you wish to get the tag from:

```
myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageName);
```

Then set the Id here, rather than in your xml.

```
myImage.setTag(R.drawable.black_rook);
```

You can then simply do:

```
int imageId = (Integer) myImage.getTag();
newImage.setImageResource(imageId);
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my layout due to your advice. Setting the image works great now.

Answer (score 3):

A tag set in xml is a string, not an integer.  You can't cast it as one.

There is a way to convert that into an integer, but I'd really question why you want to do that.  If you want that as the image, you should be setting android:src, not android:tag.

Comment: I just started learning Android, so I'm still figuring out the best practices. I changed the way I was doing it. Thanks for the advice.